# How do you create interest in your projects?

Tags: programming-practices, productivity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ideas to get you programming mojo back?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133664/ideas-to-get-you-programming-mojo-back)

Its almost 10 years for me working in Java based applications (mainly on Web). Sometimes I feel really bored of the regular work...same old problems, similar challanges etc. Since I work for a company that provides services to different customers, I change my domain from time to time, I get to know about some new things, but ultimately all are web applications and I really find nothing interesting after 6-8 months in a new project.

I would like to know from experts, how do you make working in same technology interesting?

Comment: If you want to stay with the same technology, join an open source project or create your own. If you want to stay in the same domain, read advanced books and research articles pertaining to your domain. If you want to be really interested for your whole lifetime, start learning new languages, concepts and paradigms. Start with HASKELL, Intelligent Systems and Concurrent Programming. You would just be on your toes.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, when working on a project there is a limited scope and you barely get a taste for how deeply you can dive into a domain. In most domains, there is a lot beneath the surface waiting to be uncovered by an adventurous developer. If you're bored with the mundane, take some time to explore the challenges of the domain and mull over what a solution to those challenges would look like. Perhaps mention it during a requirements gathering session (or if you don't participate in those, mention it to a lead developer who is). But be ready to back it up, because you just might get called to do it.

Other opportunities abound...find a common pattern for your development and see if you can extract it into something that can be scaffolded. When you find yourself doing the same thing repeatedly, use the computer for what it's designed so you can focus on what's different about the specific piece of functionality you're working on.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not an expert but I think that you can keep interest but associating your current job with something else you like.

Let's say you like some sport like Baseball, then you could participate in a project that creates a fantasy baseball site or something like that.

It's also possible to try some new languages, or learn new stuff, like a new methodology, design patterns, new frameworks and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Be proactive, look for new technologies and how they could fit in the projects you're working on. If you'll reach your supervisor with new ideas and even display a "proof of concept", telling him/her something like: 

"look, I checked out hibernate and I managed to accomplish stuff that would take a day of work in less than an hour - plus, it has built in security etc etc" - not only they'll appreciate your "out of the box" thinking, but you'll also build yourself a reputation as a technology leader/expert, people will come to you for advice and you'll maintain the level of interest in your projects as well as in your field. 
To sum up in one word: be proactive! ("be" is not considered as a "real" world... ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, constantly challenging yourself with new projects either in your professional environment or in your free time can be the real motivator to programming.

You can take up any area of your interest and start to develop an application. Once you begin to complete it, you will begin to realize that these challenges start to take a meaningful shift to boost your interests.

In my personal experience, my interest starts to grow when I implement a new technology or a new way of implementing what I have already done already.